# Display phone number in black color in ios devices

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have a site with contact details as follows

```
<div class="contact">Executive:<br>+1 111 111 1111<br>
Sales Phone:<br>+1 111 111 1111</div>
```

When I view the site in iphone or ipad i see the phone numbers in red color. But I want to make it black. I tried `.contact { color:black }` but of no use. Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` resolved my problem

Comment: If this answer resolves your issue, please accept it so others know the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!important`

```
.contact { color:black !important }
```

Comment: Not working still phone number is shown is red color

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` , it will override any existing style property

```
.contact { color:black !important; }
```

or wrap the phone number with `span` tag and apply inline style

```
<div class="contact">Executive:<br><span style="color:black">+1 111 111 1111</span><br>
Sales Phone:<br><span style="color:black">+1 111 111 1111</span></div>
```

inline style having higher priority

Comment: Not working still phone number is shown is red color

Comment: try `<span style="color:black !important">+1 111 111 1111</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in an anchor tax with inline styling on the tag

```
<a href="tel:+018009991234" style="color:#000000;">1-800-999-1234</a>
```

Comment: Not working still phone number is shown is red color

Comment: Really? You can always try throwing an !important tag on the end of that CSS... style="color:#000000!important;">  You can also try adding this bit of code to the head of your html file <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> and another option would be to replace some of the characters of the phone number with unicode and/or ascii codes (I've heard this works for some people, though never had the need to resort to it myself)  If you try all that and still doesn't work I'd be inclined to recommend you check your code for typos.

Comment: and be sure your doing it inline like my example.  writing the css inline vs writing it in the head will very likely result in different results because your CSS is weighted more when you write it inline.